# BigQuery: Count consecutive string matches between two fields

Tags: google-bigquery, bigquery-udf

I have two tables:

1. Master_Equipment_Index (alias **mei**) containing the columns serial_num & model_num
2. Customer Equipment Index (alias **cei**) containing the columns account_num, serial_num, & model_num

Originally, guard rails were not implemented to require model attribute input in the **mei** data whenever new serial_num records were inserted. Whenever that serial_num is later associated with a customer account in the **cei** data, the model data carries over as null.

What I want to do is backfill the missing model attributes in the **cei** data from the **mei** data based on the strongest sequential character match from other similar serial_nums in the **mei** data.

To further clarify, I don't have access to mass update the **mei** or **cei** datasets. I can formalize change requests, but I need to build the function out to prove its worth. So this has to be done outside of any mass action query updates.

| cei.account_num | cei.serial_num | cei.model | mei.serial_num | mei.model | serial_num_str_match | row_number |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123123123 | ***B4I4SXT1***708 | null | ***B4I4SXT1***78A | Model_Series1 | 8 | 1 |
| 123123123 | ***B4I4SXT***1708 | null | ***B4I4SXT***AS34 | Model_Series2 | 7 | 2 |

In the table example above row_number 1 has a higher consecutive string match count than row_number 2. I want to only return row_number 1 and populate **cei**.model with **mei**.model's value.

| cei.account_num | cei.serial_num | cei.model | mei.serial_num | mei.model | serial_num_str_match | row_number |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123123123 | ***B4I4SXT1***708 | ***Model_Series1*** | ***B4I4SXT1***78A | Model_Series1 | 8 | 1 |

To give an idea as to scale:
The **mei** data contains 1 million records and the **cei** data contains 50,000 records. I would have to take and perform this string match for every single **cei**.account_num, **cei**.serial_num where the **cei**.model data is null.

With mac addresses, the first 6 characters identify the vendor and I could look at things similarly in the sample SQL below to help reduce the volume of transactional 1:Many lookups taking place:

```
/* need to define function */
create temp function string_match_function(x any type, y any type) as (
  syntax to generate consecutive string count matches between x and y
);

select * from (
select
  c.account_num,
  c.serial_num,
  m.model,
  row_number() over(partition by c.account_num, c.serial_num order by serial_num_str_match desc) seq
from (
     select 
       c.account_num, 
       c.serial_num, 
       m.model,

       needed: string_match_function(c.serial_num, m.serial_num) as serial_num_str_match

     from (
          select * from cei where model is null
          ) c
     join (
          select * from mei where model is not null
          ) m on substr(c.serial_num,1,6) = substr(m.serial_num,1,6)
) as a
) as b
where seq = 1
```

I've looked at different options, some coming from https://hoffa.medium.com/new-in-bigquery-persistent-udfs-c9ea4100fd83, but I'm not finding what I need.

Any insight or direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This UDF function counts the equal charachters in each string from the begin:

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION string_match_function(x string, y string)
RETURNS int64
LANGUAGE js
AS r"""
  var i=0;
  var max_len= Math.min(x.length,y.length);
    for(i=0;i<max_len;i++){
        if(x[i]!=y[i]) {return i;}
    }
  return i;
""";

select string_match_function("12a345","1234")
```

gives 2, because both start with `12`

Comment: I thought commented yesterday, but that doesn't appear to be the case. This was exactly what  was looking for. Thank you so much!